# Vuejs Error: Unknown custom element did you register the component correctly

Tags: vue.js

I have different types of cells and I want to automatically get the right cell component depending on the input data.
So I created a `Cell.vue` component, which does this

```
// Cell.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="cellComponent" v-bind="cellProps"></component>
    </div>
<template>

<script>
import Cell1 from '...'
import Cell2 from '...'
import Cell3 from '...'
import SpecialCell from '...'

export default {
    name: 'Cell',
    props: ['data'],
    ...
    // get cell component and props depending on data
    computed: {
        cellComponent() {
            switch(this.data.key) {
                case 'cell1':
                    return Cell1;
                ...
                case 'specialCell':
                    return SpecialCell;
            }
        }

    }
}
</script
```

This works so far. Now, the `SpecialCell.vue` imports the `Cell.vue`, but takes care of, that only `Cell1.vue`, `Cell2.vue`, `Cell3.vue` are called, so here is no recursion.

```
// SpecialCell.vue
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <table-cell></table-cell>
        ...
    </div>
<template>

<script>
import Cell from '...'

export default {
    name: 'SpecialCell'
    props: [....],
    components: {
        'table-cell': Cell
    }
    ...
}
</script
```

Still, der following error occurs `Unknown custom element: <table-cell> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.` and the `table-cell` component is not rendered. So I added a name property for each cell type, without success.

The strange thing is, that I only get this error, when I reload the page. When I change the name of a function and let vue reload the page (npm run serve), the `table-cell` component is rendered properly.

If I copy the `Cell.vue` and reference this copied component in `SpecialCell.vue` everything works finde. Of course I could create a mixin or extend the cell component, to avoid code duplication, but I want to understand the problem and maybe it is possible to solve the problem without creating another file.

Does anyone know a solution?

Edit: The problem is this line `import SpecialCell from '...'` in `Cell.vue`. When I use lazy loading in `cellComponent()` there is no error

```
cellComponent() {
    switch(this.data.key) {
        case 'cell1':
            return Cell1;
        ...
        case 'specialCell':
            return () => import('.../SpecialCell');
    }
}
```

Comment: what value does "cellComponent" hold?

Comment: can you share the data block as well?

Comment: I added the cellComponent computed property to the code ;)
I don't have a data block. If you mean the data variable, the content should be irrelevant for the problem.